# Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object

Tags: reactjs, babel-loader

Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
[eslint]
src\components\Product\ProductDetails.js
Line 0:  Parsing error: [BABEL] D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\src\components\Product\ProductDetails.js: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object'
Require stack:

- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\create.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\index.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\module-types.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\configuration.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\index.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\index.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules@rollup\plugin-babel\dist\index.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules\workbox-build\build\lib\bundle.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules\workbox-webpack-plugin\build\generate-sw.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules\workbox-webpack-plugin\build\index.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js (While processing: "D:\Mern-stack-project\full-mern\cs\mern\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\prod.js")

I am geeting this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.